# Can we set up a network on cellullar data service?

Tags: connection

I'm trying to research the possibility of setting up my desktop on my cellular network.  Can this be done in windows 10Pro. I don't see anything in internet options? I don't see why I should need a separate service for the internet. My phone runs solely on cellular data. Is this a possibility? My phone service offers hotspot, but does that mean I would be running the PC off my phone? I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, thought frustratingly the details depend on your phone and isp more than your PC.

You ought to be able to simply set up a hotspot on most phones and trivially connect your PC to it with a wireless card.

You could also tether via USB with many phones, which I find more reliable with a single PC

It's worth remembering that PC's tend to not limit the amount of data used - you would want to set warnings on your phone if you have limits and remember to set the connection as metered if it is on windows to limit updates and such